# Gratis Android application that can download videos from YouTube

Tags: gratis, android, download-manager, youtube

I'm looking a gratis Android application that can download videos from YouTube. Neither NewPipe nor Videoder seems to be working anymore to download YouTube videos. I want a GUI (e.g., YouTube-dl CLI isn't an option).

Comment: I'm not using any of them on my Android device, but my usual hint applies here, too: find a bunch of them in [my corresponding app list](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_video_downloader) if you just want a downloader. If you also want to play videos in-app without prior download, I'd go with NewPipe as suggested by Locksmith (it's even available at F-Droid). If you also want to skip sponsor-blocks, there's [a fork in my repo](https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/index/apk/org.polymorphicshade.newpipe) taking care for that.

Comment: @Izzy thanks, great list! Will refer to it NewPipe stops working

Comment: If NewPipe stops working it's usually due to changes on YT's end, and in most cases fixed quickly. I recommend using their own F-Droid repo for fast updates.

Comment: @Izzy thanks, agreed, coincidentally I had the same issue last time I tried about six months ago so I thought the project was down for good. Happy that it's still well alive!

Comment: And pretty active, with a responsive dev :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are referring to, literally just downloaded a video with NewPipe.

[NewPipe](https://newpipe.net/) a FOSS project with an active community, your best course would most likely be to find whether others are experiencing the same issue you have, and if not, report your issue in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/TeamNewPipe/NewPipe/issues)

Comment: Thanks, good catch, new pipe wasn't working yesterday, saw an update today, installed it and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[TubeMate](http://tubemate.net/) is something you should definitely look into. Make sure to only download it from the official website or one of the mirrors there. It can also be used with other video streaming websites.

Comment: Thanks, great app! [Does Tubemate use some peer-to-peer network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242901/12202)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'm quite sure it's not a peer-to-peer protocol. It's most likely invoking a process on an AWS instance to parse the video on the web page, and then your device handles the download and the conversion.